# Tooltips for QDockWidget close button & float button?

Tags: qt, qt4, qdockwidget

Is there a way to set a tool tip text for the close button & float button in a QDockWidget ?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As ixSci mentioned, using `setTitleBarWidget()` is a potential way of solving this problem. Having said that I was looking for a much simpler solution, ideally using `QSS` (Qt Style Sheets). So after digging into the source code of `QDockWidget` I found an alternative way which suits my requirement better.

I wanted to find the place these `float` and `close` buttons are created. That is inside `QDockWidgetPrivate::init()` method in `QDockWidget.cpp`.

As for an example, the `float` button is created like this:

```
QAbstractButton *button = new QDockWidgetTitleButton(q);
button->setObjectName(QLatin1String("qt_dockwidget_floatbutton"));
QObject::connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), q, SLOT(_q_toggleTopLevel()));
layout->setWidgetForRole(QDockWidgetLayout::FloatButton, button);
```

Now all I need is to use the flexibility of Qt Style Sheets, for that I need only the Object Name, in this case it's "`qt_dockwidget_floatbutton`"

So all you need to do, to set tooltips for `Close` and `Float` buttons of a `QDockWidget`, is to add following two lines of styles in your application style sheet

```
QAbstractButton#qt_dockwidget_closebutton{qproperty-toolTip: "Close";}
QAbstractButton#qt_dockwidget_floatbutton{qproperty-toolTip: "Restore";}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement whatever title widget you want and set it with `setTitleBarWidget()`. In that widget you can add whatever buttons with tooltips you need.